# Inserting value in Hashtable results in error: string not matched (IndexError)

Tags: ruby, cucumber

in a cucumber script, I defined:

```
Before do
@hashtable = Hash.new

Given xxxx do |arg1, arg2|
    @hashtable = @deal.Insert(@hashtable, arg1, arg2)
```

the @deal.Insert is defined as:

```
def Insert(hashtable, key, value)
    hashtable[key] = value
```

when I run the cucumber script, it throws error:

```
string not matched (IndexError)
./lib/deal.rb:... in '[]='
./lib/deal.rb:... in 'Insert'
....
```

As I am new to Ruby, I am not sure what happened here? is it possible that the Insert take hashtable NOT as a hash but as something else so that the indexing is invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have returned hashtable:

```
def Insert(hashtable, key, value)
    hashtable[key] = value
    return hashtable
```

without this I think the Insert returned something else which leads to the problem.